# How to submit data from my iphone apps to my Facebook wall by titanium

Tags: facebook, titanium, dom-events, titanium-mobile

I am new with titanium. I have made iPhone apps by titanium which show a product list. If a click on it it brings a details page as every normal apps. I need to know about process if I want to submit the product details from my app to my Facebook wall. I studied about the Facebook API for titanium, but I am bit of confused about the process because I am new with titanium and Facebook application. Please help me.

Comment: See this https://gist.github.com/914807

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find built in facebook integration on Titanium Kitchen Sink example app. Here is the link of git repository

[Titanium Kitchen Sink Facebook Example](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/mashups/facebook_publish_stream.js)